# SO_KEEPALIVE for PHP stream sockets

Tags: php, sockets

How to set SO_KEEPALIVE for php stream sockets?
Is there any function similar to `setsockopt` with `SO_KEEPALIVE` option?

I am creating a server stream socket with SSL added to its context.
Currently my server is unable to find out when a client terminated its connection abnormally(say, client gets crashed).

Comment: [`socket_set_option($socket, SO_KEEPALIVE)`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.socket-set-option.php)?

Comment: @user555 does `socket_set_option` work on stream sockets?

Answer (score 2):

You need to [socket_import_stream](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.socket-import-stream.php) first:

```
$stream = stream_socket_client('tcp://127.0.0.1:5672');
$sock = socket_import_stream($stream);
socket_set_option($sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_KEEPALIVE, 1);
```

Comment: On Linux, you can confirm the change has enabled keepalive by running `netstat -anpo` and checking for `keepalive` in the last column.